# How to make two slideable sections on android device screen?

Tags: android, homescreen

How to create custom view with two independent sections, each slideable? Example would be iPad Zillow -> http://www.zillow.com/ipad/

I was wondering if this can also be done on the home screen and not only in new app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create custom view with two independent sections, each slideable?

I doubt that would be a "custom view" in Android. The main Zillow-style activity would be a `MapView`, a `ListView`, and an `ImageView` (for the photo), using `LinearLayouts` or a `RelativeLayout` for organization.

> I was wondering if this can also be done on the home screen and not only in new app...

If you write your own home screen, sure.